# How to modify an array of objects to new values based on another array in ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 arrays as below, I want to update the `array1` value based on `array2` value for example in `array1.name` I want to set it's value to `array2.uName`'s value and updated array should be `const array1 = [{name: "aman", age:"26"},...]`. How to achieve this in React?

Actually I want to map through new modified array and return an `component` with the data combined both arrays but array1 should be updated based on array2 which I am getting from `api`.

```js
const array1 = [{
    name: "abc",
    age: "123"
  },
  {
    name: "bcd",
    age: "456"
  },
];

const array2 = [{
    uAddress: "India",
    uAge: "26",
    uNum: "12345",
    uName: "aman"
  },
  {
    uAge: "46",
    uAddress: "India",
    uNum: "6789",
    uName: "rohan"
  },
];
```

Comment: I think you might want to modify the arrays through input events, is that right? Can you show the React component where you want to do this? Or do you just want array1 to always be defined as `array1 = [{ name: array2[0].uName, age: array2[0].uAge }]`? I'll need a little more context to help you out hehe.

Comment: Please read updated post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `forEach` to iterate through your list, and set the fields accordingly.

```
array1.forEach((person, index) => { 
  person.name = array2[index].uName; 
  person.age = array2[index].uAge;
})
```

Result:
[ { name: 'aman', age: '26' }, { name: 'rohan', age: '46' } ]

update:

```
array1.forEach((person, index) => {
  let copyFromPerson = array2.find(ele => ele.id === person.id)
  person.name = copyFromPerson.uName; 
  person.age = copyFromPerson.uAge;
})
```

Comment: Please read updated post.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a React-specific thing, but if you use a `forEach` higher-order function you can achieve this update.

```
array1.forEach((item, index) => { 
   item.age = array2[index].uAge
   item.name = array2[index].uName
  })

console.log(array1[0]) // {name: "aman", age: "26"}
```

Note: In the description, you said `array1.name`. I just want to make sure you know that that won't work. array1 is an array of objects, so in order to use dot notation to access a property, you need to clarify which index of the array you want access. Such as `array1[0]` or `array1[1]`. Then you can do `array1[0].name`

Comment: Please read updated post.